# Jest: Different results with --watch and --coverage

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, babeljs

I have a test for a custom error that passes when ran with `jest --watch` but fails when ran with `jest --coverage`.

`jest --watch`
[image]

`jest --coverage`
[image]

It seems like they're running with different versions of babel.

Has anyone ran into this before? What should I check? Any other information I could provide?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: Might it be because some of the previously-ran tests has a shared dependency with `util/validation/test.js` and it has some side-effects? You can check if you press `a` in watch mode to run all of the tests and if they fail to share the tests

Comment: @Teneff Good thought but same results...